# Google Coral mini pci-e accelerator

Tags: tensorflow-lite, tpu, google-coral

Do any of you use the google coral accelerator mini pci-e version?
I'm interested in whether this card will work on an older laptop with a mini pci-e slot in version 1.1? I asked the manufacturer's support but I did not get a clear answer.
As far as I know, mini pci-e cards in version 2.0 and higher should normally work in slot 1.x but with limited transfers.

Best ragards,
Maciej Czarnacki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question in the most honest way, we do have the requirements listed [here](https://coral.ai/docs/m2/get-started/#requirements). To quote:

```
Requirements
To get started, you need a Linux computer with the following specs:

* x86-64 or ARM64 system architecture
* An available Mini PCIe or M.2 key slot
* Debian 6.0 Linux distribution or higher, or any derivative thereof (such as Ubuntu 10.0+)
* Python 3.5 or higher
```

However, this is obviously not the answer you are looking for. You see, the problem is that it is very hard to predict whether or not if your hardware will work before trying it. This is because there are tons of hardware out there and we cannot test all of them. We have seen unsupported platform works with our hardware, and vice versa. Some times the bug is on the host machine and it is out of our hand, sometimes we find bug on our drivers which we are always improving. So I hope you understand that this isn't something we can just say for sure.